# How to fix: " AccessDeniedException: You are in ap-southeast-1, but your directory region is us-east-1. Please use us-east-1 as region."

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-quicksight

Im trying out aws quicksight getting started tutorial:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/embedded-dashboards-with-iam-setup-step-3.html

Im at a step to use

```
     aws quicksight register-user --aws-account-id XXXXXXXXX --namespace 
     default --identity-type IAM --iam-arn 
     "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/qsembed" --user-role READER --session-name 
     "XXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXX.com" --email XXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXX .com --region ap- southeast-1
```

however I get hit with

"An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the RegisterUser operation: You are in ap-southeast-1, but your directory region is us-east-1. Please use us-east-1 as region.
"

the quicksight and main AWS accounts are both on singapore (ap-southeast-1). No documentation seems to solve this problem

Help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Make sure that your IAM permission are not only for ap-southeast.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! May I ask where or how to change allowed regions for the policy ?

Answer (score 4):

Quicksight maintains user register in one region and analysis and dashboard can be created in different regions. As the error message says you have to use --region us-east-1.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little difference between default region and the region you are in

By default us-east-1 aka N. Virginia for quicksight is default main region, so when you are trying to access quicksight account settings, it says you should switch to the N. Virginia region to get access and modify settings

And requests like create_namespace, register_user should be run in the default region us-east-1

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, some time back, perhaps early 2022 QuickSight added ability to customize your identity region at time of signup (previously was only US East 1). Unfortunately you cannot change this after the fact. You would need to create a new account or unsub/resubscribe your account.

Can reference this article as you are signing up again (see Region Selection section):
https://community.amazonquicksight.com/t/considerations-in-setting-up-a-quicksight-account/1325